# How can I get turtles to turn around at edge of world and avoid each other without getting stuck between the two commands?

Tags: netlogo

I am using `netlogo` to simulate turtles randomly walking around, searching for something. I have two rules: I want turtles to turn around when they get to the edge of the world (or just turn slightly so they are not stuck on the edge) and I want turtles to avoid each other. I have created the following code:

```
to setup
 clear-all
 let ycord one-of (list min-pycor max-pycor)
  crt 3 [
    setxy random-pxcor ycord
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    pen-down
  ]

  reset-ticks
end


to go
  tick
  ask turtles [search]
end


to search

      (ifelse
      ;if at edge of world turn around
      (xcor <= min-pxcor or ycor <= min-pycor or xcor >= max-pxcor or ycor >= max-pycor) [
        set heading heading + 180
      ]
      ;if any other turtles are near turn away
      any? other turtles in-radius 4 [                    
        let closest min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
        face closest
        set heading heading + 180
      ]
      [right (random 21) - 10]
    )

  ;step forward
  fd 1

end
```

Boundaries are set not to wrap. It works okay except turtles get stuck in corners where they just bounce back and forth, or they get stuck between avoiding another turtle and turning around at the edge. I want them to seamlessly not get stuck at any edges and avoid each other with the goal of maximizing the area covered by all turtles. Also turtles are meant to simulate humans if that adds context.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the [Random Balls](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/RandomBalls) example model of the NetLogo models library, it has a neat way to implement the bouncing at the world edges.

What might also help is to let your turtles do multiple smaller steps and adjust their heading in between. Thereby they start adjusting earlier which might help in some cases. For you, this could for example look like this:

```
to search
    repeat 4 [
      (ifelse
      ;if at edge of world turn around
      (xcor <= min-pxcor or ycor <= min-pycor or xcor >= max-pxcor or ycor >= max-pycor) [
        set heading heading + 180
      ]
      ;if any other turtles are near turn away
      any? other turtles in-radius 4 [                    
        let closest min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
        face closest
        set heading heading + 180
      ]
      [right (random 21) - 10]
    )

    ;step forward
    fd 0.25
  ]

end
```

Comment: Hi @lmf0845 I appreciate your response. but I can't get it working...for reference I used `random-seed 13` in my set up function and I copied your search function into my model. The turtles do not seem to move at all.

Comment: Try to change two things: 1. wrap your world and 2. don't place the turtles right on the edge of the world (e.g. `let ycord one-of (list (min-pycor + 0.1) (max-pycor - 0.1)`)

Answer (score 1):

Achieved something as you asked by changing your 'search' procedure to the following:

```
to search
  
  (ifelse
    ;if at edge of world turn around
    xcor <= min-pxcor + 0.25 [set heading (random 180)]
    ycor <= min-pycor + 0.25 [set heading one-of (list (270 + random 90)(random 90))]
    xcor >= max-pxcor - 0.25 [set heading (180 + random 180)]
    ycor >= max-pycor - 0.25 [set heading (90 + random 180)]
    
    ;if any other turtles are near turn away
    any? other turtles in-radius 4 [                    
      let closest min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
      face closest
      set heading heading + 180
    ]
    [right (random 21) - 10]
  )
  
  ;step forward
  fd 1

end
```

This helps in 2 ways. On the one hand, turtles don't get as easily stuck because randomness in their turns helps to avoid getting two spinning next to each other because their only two options are not valid to keep moving. On the other hand, this didn't avoid them from getting stuck sometimes, because they were not in the exact limit of the world (15.98... instead of 16, for example). The 0.25 margin from the edges avoids this.

Hope this gets your turtles doing what you wanted!

Comment: Hi @Pol thanks for responding. Your solution kind of works but I'm still having agents stuck in the corner/near other agents for a long time. I think if you add `random-seed 13` to the set up function you will see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Consider expanding logic so that there are first tests, then logic based on results. So you'll have a series of assignments that hold the results of the tests, then an ifelse chain that examines the results.

Like

```
Let at-h-wall? abs ycor <= min-pycor
Let at-h-wall? Abs xcor <= min-pxcor
Let at-wall? At-h-wall? or at-v-wall?
Let crowded? Any? Other turtles in-radius 2
Let blocked? At-wall? And any? Other turtles-on patch-at-heading-and
Let in-corner? At-h-wall? and at-v-wall?
Let trapped? ....
```

And so on.

Another way is for the walker to form an agentset of neighboring patches that meet the criteria for being clear. So,

```
Let clear-patches
   neighbors with 
   [ not ( 
       any? Turtles-here 
       or abs pxcor = max-pxcor 
       or abs pycor = max-pycor
     )
   ]
if any? Clear-patches
[ move-to one-of clear-patches
]
```